# USB and a personal-created device interfacing in Windows using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, usb, interfacing

I know how to interface using the parallel port and also have a little idea on serial port interfacing. But is there a way to interface using the USB port in Windows? Or any links that would give tutorials on how to do this?

Specifically, I wanted to know the programming side of it.

I don't know how to start. I have searched into google but I have not seen any code samples.

Thanks in advance and Happy New Year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB programming is considerably more complex than serial or parallel port programming. For writing USB drivers for Windows, you'll probably need the [Windows WDK](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/Devtools/wdk/default.mspx). However, for a device you build yourself you can start with implementing a serial port class driver in your device, so that it shows up as a new serial port in Windows. The HID is another potentially useful driver class, generally used for some kind of input device.

I would recommend a good book if you want to do USB programming, for example Jan Axelson's [USB Complete](http://www.lvr.com/usbc.htm). And a real *hardware* protocol analyser is indispensable.

Answer (score 2):

Found an interesting blog post http://yeohhs.blogspot.com/2006/08/programming-usb-port.html
it mentions a library 'libusb' and a wrapper for the same. The library is a GNU project. The library and documentation of the same may prove useful. The API documentation of libusb is here: http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/